# I'm working on a webiste and this code in the Gutenberg editor doesn't make any sense. Is this normal, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm doing a job for someone and I basically have to fix the mistakes of my predecessor. There is already an existing page and stuff (I've never really worked with Wordpress before) And I'm finding this code to look like some kind of absolute garbage. I'm super confused just looking at it. This looks nothing like HTML. Could someone tell me what's going on here please? Thanks ahead.

```
[fusion_builder_container hundred_percent="no" hundred_percent_height="no" hundred_percent_height_scroll="no" hundred_percent_height_center_content="yes" equal_height_columns="no" hide_on_mobile="small-visibility,medium-visibility,large-visibility" status="published" border_style="solid" padding_top="8%" padding_bottom="8%" gradient_start_position="0" gradient_end_position="100" gradient_type="linear" radial_direction="center center" linear_angle="180" background_position="center center" background_repeat="no-repeat" fade="no" background_parallax="none" enable_mobile="no" parallax_speed="0.3" background_blend_mode="none" video_aspect_ratio="16:9" video_loop="yes" video_mute="yes" filter_hue="0" filter_saturation="100" filter_brightness="100" filter_contrast="100" filter_invert="0" filter_sepia="0" filter_opacity="100" filter_blur="0" filter_hue_hover="0" filter_saturation_hover="100" filter_brightness_hover="100" filter_contrast_hover="100" filter_invert_hover="0" filter_sepia_hover="0" filter_opacity_hover="100" filter_blur_hover="0" admin_label="Introduction" admin_toggled="yes" flex_column_spacing="0px" type="flex" menu_anchor="wiezijnwij" class="wiezijnwij" id="wiezijnwij" background_color="#ffffff"][fusion_builder_row][fusion_builder_column type="1_1" type="1_1" layout="1_1" spacing="" center_content="no" link="" target="_self" min_height="" hide_on_mobile="small-visibility,medium-visibility,large-visibility" class="" id="" hover_type="none" border_color="" border_style="solid" border_position="all" border_radius="" box_shadow="no" dimension_box_shadow="" box_shadow_blur="0" box_shadow_spread="0" box_shadow_color="" box_shadow_style="" padding_top="" padding_right="" padding_bottom="" padding_left="" margin_top="" margin_bottom="" background_type="single" gradient_start_color="" gradient_end_color="" gradient_start_position="0" gradient_end_position="100" gradient_type="linear" radial_direction="center center" linear_angle="180" background_color="" background_image="" background_image_id="" background_position="left top" background_repeat="no-repeat" background_blend_mode="none" animation_type="fade" animation_direction="down" animation_speed="1.0" animation_offset="" filter_type="regular" filter_hue="0" filter_saturation="100" filter_brightness="100" filter_contrast="100" filter_invert="0" filter_sepia="0" filter_opacity="100" filter_blur="0" filter_hue_hover="0" filter_saturation_hover="100" filter_brightness_hover="100" filter_contrast_hover="100" filter_invert_hover="0" filter_sepia_hover="0" filter_opacity_hover="100" filter_blur_hover="0" last="true" element_content="" first="true" border_sizes_top="0px" border_sizes_bottom="0px" border_sizes_left="0px" border_sizes_right="0px"][fusion_title title_type="text" rotation_effect="bounceIn" display_time="1200" highlight_effect="circle" loop_animation="off" highlight_width="9" highlight_top_margin="0" before_text="" rotation_text="" highlight_text="" after_text="" content_align="center" size="2" font_size="" animated_font_size="" line_height="" letter_spacing="" text_color="#3bb2d3" animated_text_color="" highlight_color="" style_type="default" sep_color="" hide_on_mobile="small-visibility,medium-visibility,large-visibility" class="" id="" fusion_font_variant_title_font="" margin_top="25px" margin_top_small="50"]
```

All the rest of the code looks more or less like this.

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks, I'll try it there

Answer (score 0):

This is CSS code. You can ignore it. All of this makes sense, it displays the Code editor. So just ignore it. This is the frontend code.

Comment: Then where can I actually edit the websites code? Because I'm not finding that